# Stable way to transfer mails between GMail account? Thunderbird fails

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap, applescript

I want to transfer ≈ 500 mails between two GMail accounts, from A to B. The mails are quite big, on average 5 MB or so. They span 10 years and I have split them into separate mailboxes (labels) by year on A.

I then tried using Thunderbird and IMAP to transfer the first year (around 50 messages). It failed after 12 messages. I tried several times, it always failed after 12 messages, the same 12 messages (Thundebird transferred them from newest to oldest, independently of how I sorted the mailbox).

I then tried to sync/download all messages and go offline and make the transfer when offline. As long as I was offline the transfer worked/looked fine but as soon as I went online again and Thunderbird synced the changes, only the same 12 messages was transferred.

Now I deselected the 12 messages already transferred and tried (several times, every time with the same result) to transfer the remaining 38 messages. 37 messages transferred fine, forcing me to manually find the remaining culprit.

Finally I manually transferred the last message - which also transferred fine on the first attempt. WTF!?!?!?

Now I am trying to transfer the next year, and it is the same result again. A bunch of messages is transferred and then it fails. If I repeat it, exactly the same messages are transferred before it fails. If I try to transfer the remaining messages, another bunch is transferred and then it fails. Again and again.

**Is there some way, with Thunderbird or some other tool, to make these transfers stable? Ideally, I think, would be a script that transferred one message at the time and then verified that the transfer was successful.**

---

Edit: After some more trial-and-error, I have come to some conclusions:

1. I spent a few hours trying to transfer 180 messages, but it only transferred 2-5 in each "sessions" (I selected all messages in the source account and copied them to the destination account).

When done with that I put it aside for a day. When I resumed I tried to transfer 50 messages - and was successful in the first attempt. I copied another 50 messages, successful again. Rinse and repeat a couple of times (I divided the messages by year, when performing these copy-actions), no problem at all.

I **think** the problem I had the day before could be that GMail allows a limited number of connections/sessions and if you fail a couple of times, the connections are left open which causes problems. When I put work aside for a day, these stalled connections might have timed out and been released, making it "easier" or more stable to perform these copies.

2. I also created a crude Applescript that allowed me to copy one message at the time. That "solved" the first issue.

It is very basic, it just sends keystrokes, arrow up/down and then `Message` → `Copy to [destination mailbox] again`

To use it you first have to manually copy a message from the source to the destination mailbox so that the `Copy to` menu option is "setup" correctly.

I am sure you can do something similar with the scripting options available for Windows (like Autokey) and Linux.

If I need to use it again, I will make the algorithm slightly smarter:

1. Manually sort the mailbox by message size
2. Start with the smallest message
3. Increase the sleep timer with 5 seconds, or something like that (depending on the distribution of the sizes among the messages you want to transfer - in my case it was 500 kB up to 20 MB), in every loop. That way you don't need to wait 2 minutes for all messages that should be transferred.

Here is the script:

```
tell application "Thunderbird"
    activate
    delay 2
    repeat 70 times
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "m" using {command down, option down}
        delay 117
        tell application "System Events" to key code 126 --arrow up
        delay 1
    end repeat
    beep
end tell
```

Comment: First, if it fails a t a specific point, look for a damaged message, e.g., header only. Second, it might be easiest to transfer all messages to a *local* Thunderbird folder, and then from that to the second GMail account. This avoids having a wait at GMail block transfer, either at receiving or transmitting end.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Looking for a corrupt message was my first suspicion but since all messages transferred fine when doing them in smaller groups or one by one I don't think that is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Web interface of Gmail with the tool of *Import mail and contacts*.
The transfer will be done by Gmail servers and will not use your computer.

**Sending Gmail account**

- Open Settings and go to "Forwarding and POP/IMAP
- Select "Enable POP for all mail (even mail that’s already been downloaded)"
- Click "Save Changes"
- Sign off

**Receiving Gmail account**

- Go to Settings > Accounts and Import
- Select "Import mail and contacts"
- Type the email address the Sending Gmail account and select Continue
- Choose "Continue" again on the Step 1 screen
- Log in to the Receiving Gmail account
- Give Gmail permission to access it by selecting Allow when prompted
- Close the window that says Authentication successful.
- Choose Start import
- Select OK to return to Gmail’s settings page.

Wait for Gmail to transfer all your emails between the two Gmail accounts.
You can monitor the process from the "Accounts and Imports" screen.

Comment: I tried this approach about 2-3 years ago and it ended up dumping a load of valid emails (which were previously in the inbox) into spam, marking everything as unread and messing up stars and categories. I ended up using Thunderbird to do the migration instead. Hopefully Google have sorted these problems out by now!

Comment: How does this affect non-default folders? _(POP doesn't support folders, so does Gmail mitigate this on the backend?)_